# datatable concatenar dos valores en una columna

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo un **datatable**. Estoy usando los datos de una base de datos y quiero que el nombre y el apellido salga en una sola columna.

Este es el **json** que uso en el js

```
"columns":[          
      {"data":"nombres"}, //aqui me gustaria sacar el nombre y el apellido          
  ],
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español!  Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para empezar y comprender como funcionamos y así poderte ayudar mejor.  La información que has puesto en tu pregunta es insuficiente para darte una respuesta correcta. Necesitamos ver la consulta de la base de datos y como llamas a datatable completamente, y seguramente más cosas. [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/510708/edit) la pregunta y añade esa información si quieres ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Para columnas personalizadas tenemos la propiedad `render` que hay buenos ejemplos en la [documentacíon](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/data_rendering.html)

```
"columns":[{
  "data":"nombres",
  render: function ( data, type, row ) {
      // esto es lo que se va a renderizar como html
      return `<b>${row.nombres}</b> ${row.apellidos}`; 
    }
 }],
```